# WPF DataType unable to reference 3rd party object type

Tags: wpf

I'm trying to use a 3rd party DLL object type for a data template in WPF treeview. For some reason, the "rdb:Element" object type is not found, however I can use all day in code, and even bind to this object type in other places, but cant seem to reference it in this way. Can someone help me understand why this certain datatype is not available to me in this way?

Please see the " " line in code below. I'm getting "Element does not exist in name space..." error.

```
<Window x:Class="Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LotSpec.Revit"
    xmlns:rdb="clr-namespace:Autodesk.Revit.DB;assembly=RevitAPI"
    xmlns:m="clr-namespace:LotSpec.Revit.Models"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid>

    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding ObjectOptions}">
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type m:ObjectOpt}" ItemsSource="{Binding Elems}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Rule}"/>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type rdb:Element}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ElemToDisplayName}}" Margin="3"/>
            </DataTemplate>

        </TreeView.Resources>
    </TreeView>

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure why it wouldn't allow you to bind to a `Element` type, but here's something that I do all the time and why I think it's not a great idea to bind to `Element` objects.

Normally when dealing with WPF you will need things like two-way bindings. Clicking a checkbox in your UI should update a property and vice versa. To make sure that works well, you need these classes to implement `IPropertyChanged` interface. The problem with binding to an object from external library is that you don't have control over what interfaces were implemented there. Sure, you can probably extend them. I would have been game with that. Anyways, the point is, that when doing WPF I like to have control, and always create wrapper classes for any Revit DB objects. For example, I need a UI element that is a checkbox, and uses a name to compare between objects. I can do that by creating a wrapper class around `Element` from Revit API. In this case, I am wrapping a `DimensionType`.

```
public class DimensionStyleWrapper : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public object Self { get; set; }

    public DimensionStyleWrapper()
    {
    }

    public DimensionStyleWrapper(DimensionType t)
    {
        Name = t.Name;
        Id = t.Id.IntegerValue;
        Self = t;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Method that validates that the current Dimension Style Wrapper is still a valid
    /// object in context of provided Revit Document.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="doc">Revit Document.</param>
    /// <returns>True if wrapper is valid or was validated, otherwise false.</returns>
    public bool Validate(Document doc)
    {
        var e = doc.GetElement(new ElementId(Id));
        if (e == null || e.Name != Name)
        {
            var dt = new FilteredElementCollector(doc)
                .OfClass(typeof(DimensionType))
                .WhereElementIsElementType()
                .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == Name);
            if (dt != null)
            {
                Id = dt.Id.IntegerValue;
                Self = dt;

                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var item = obj as ViewWrapper;
        return item != null && Name.Equals(item.Name);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Name.GetHashCode();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propname)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propname));
    }
}
```

Notice the `IPropertyChanged` interface. That comes handy when I use that class in WPF `ComboBox`, or a `CheckBox` and need a two way binding. I have also created my own `Equals` override to use the object `Name` as a way to determine if two objects are the same. I also have a `Validate` routine in there, that makes sure that if given class was serialized from JSON, that it actually exists in the given model. For the kicker I have a property called `Self` that I use to store a reference to the original `DimensionType` that came from the DB. I don't always use that, but sometimes it comes handy. I can always get the latest object using the `Id` and `doc.GetElement()`. Anyways, the point I am making is that for WPF UI design, you want to have full control over the behavior of objects that you bind to, hence creating a custom wrapper class, has been a good workflow for me.